# simultaneous click checkboxes

Tags: php, html

How do I call a method when both checkboxes are ticked in php?

```
if (isset($_POST['check1'])) 
{data1();}

else if (isset($_POST['check2']) 
{data2();}
```

The above works perfectly for single checkboxes. The moment I tick both it only brings up data1(). I tried the following.

```
else if(isset($_POST['check1']) && ($_POST['check2'])) 
{data1and2();}
```

and

```
else if(isset($_POST['check1']) && ($_POST['check2']))
{data1and2();}
```

Comment: What is wrong with @Austin Brunkhorst's answer? You don't need to use "else". You can just have 2 if statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `isset` for `$_POST['check2']`

```
 if(isset($_POST['check1']) && isset($_POST['check2'])) {
    data1and2();
 }
```

And this condition should be first.

```
 if(isset($_POST['check1']) && isset($_POST['check2'])) {
    data1and2();
 } else if (isset($_POST['check1'])) {
    data1();
 } else if (isset($_POST['check2'])) {
    data2();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not separate if statements?

```
if(isset($_POST['check1']))
    data1();

if(isset($_POST['check2']))
    data2();
```

if you need a different function for when they're both checked you can do something like this.

```
list($flag1, $flag2) = array(isset($_POST['check1']), isset($_POST['check2']));

if($flag1 && flag2)
    data1and2();
else if($flag1)
    data1();
else if($flag2)
    data2();
```

Comment: He want to call `data1and2()` if all checked. this will call both `data1()` and `data2()`, but not `data1and2()`

Comment: I didn't down vote, but `list($flag1, $flag2) = array(isset($_POST['check1']), isset($_POST['check2']));
` is doing something wrong. Why not assign directly with `$flag1 = isset($_POST['check1']); $flag2=isset($_POST['check2']);`

Comment: It went from 1 to 0 but now it's back at 1. The point of the list operation is to be able to assign multiple variables on one line, being more intuitive for adding more posts to check if needed in the future.

Comment: "It went from 1 to 0" doesn't mean must be a down vote, I check the votes, just because someone removed the up vote.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your logic is off. In the case of singles, this logic is fine, but if you check both, the `isset` on `check1` will be triggered, the script not knowing that it should check that it should take a different action if both are checked. Your best bet is to put your `if` that checks for both being checked *first*, then the check for the single boxes, like so:

```
if (isset($_POST['check2'] && isset($_POST['check1']))
{data1and2();}

else if (isset($_POST['check1'])) 
{data1();}

else if (isset($_POST['check2']) 
{data2();}
```